# requests. Не могу авторизоваться на сайте

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Я писал парсер для gumtree.com это английский сайт для продаж похожий на авито. Столкнулся с тем что для просмотра номера телефона продавца сайт требует авторизоваться. Я нашел информацию в интернете и сделал все по инструкции, но парсер все равно не работает

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

HEADERS={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'
}

link='https://my.gumtree.com/login'

data_={
    "username:": "vyacheslavsavelev1977@gmail.com",
    "password:": "hPMU^CF3#$s8,5j",
    "client_id:": "",
    "scope:": "",
    "state:": "",
    "redirect_uri:": "",
    "response_type:": ""
}

session=requests.Session()
responce=session.post(link, data=data_, headers=HEADERS).text
url='https://www.gumtree.com/p/ps4/ps4-pro-death-stranding-edition-/1421204505?srn=true'

def get_html(url, params=''):
    response=session.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return response


html=get_html(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
phone=soup.find('strong', class_="txt-large txt-emphasis form-row-label").get_text()
print(phone)
```

на выходе этот код должен выдавать номер телелефона продавца. если авторизация прошла бы успешно то код выдаст полный номер телефона(07851383466), но код выдает номер телефона как для незарегистрированного на сайте пользователя(0785138XXXX). Подскажите что я делаю не так

Comment: Решения этой проблемы я не нашел, но сделал авторизацию с помощью selenium и все заработало